# Conditional CSS Class

Tags: html, css, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2, and have the following html code:

```
<ion-content padding class="messages-page-content">
    <ion-scroll scrollY="true" class="messages">
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item class="message-item" *ngFor="let item of firelist | async">
                <div [class]="'message message-me'">
                    <div class="message-content">{{item.message_text}}</div>
                    <span class="time-tick">
                        <span class="message-timestamp">{{item.timestamp | amDateFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY  h:mm a'}}</span>
                        <div *ngIf="showTick(message) === true">
                            <span class="checkmark">
                                <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
                                <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
                            </span>    
                        </div>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

If you look at this line in particular:

```
<div [class]="'message message-me'">
```

I would like to be able to dynamically change the class.

For example, something like this, but I cannot get this to work:

```
<div [class]="{{item.memberId === me.memberId ? 'message message-me' : 'message message-you'}}">
```

Where `me` is defined in the supporting `ts` file.

Any advise welcome.

**UPDATE**

Based on the advise below outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279830/change-classes-conditionally-ionic2), I try the following:

```
    <div [class]="{'message message-me' : (item.uid == me.uid), 'message message-you':(item.uid === you.uid)}">
```

Now, I just lose all my formatting but no errors. Objects `item.uid` and `me.uid` do exist.

[image]

Original code:

```
<div [class]="'message message-me'">
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

The following kind of works:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'message message-you':(item.uid === you.uid), 'message message-me':(item.uid === me.uid)}">
```

I have a list where both conditions are met, but only the right hand condition is applying the style.  If I swap the left and right conditions around, the other style works, so this suggests nothing is wrong with the data, but rather the html.

[image]

If I change it to:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'message message-me':(item.uid === me.uid), 'message message-you':(item.uid === you.uid)}">
```

I get:

[image]

I also try:

```
    <div [ngClass]="{'message message-me':(item.uid != you.uid), 'message message-you':(item.uid === you.uid)}">
```

To prove it's not a problem with the data, but only the right hand class is ever applied.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change classes conditionally Ionic2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279830/change-classes-conditionally-ionic2)

Comment: Hi Suraj, thank you for your advise once again.  I have tried what that post suggests, but lose my style altogether now. Please see UPDATE above.

Comment: you need to use ngClass attribute..not 'class' https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngClass

Comment: Thank you Suraj, it works now. I needed to use ngClass

Comment: It kind of works (just one side), see update above.

Comment: maybe you.uid is not the correct value? item.uid === you.uid is failing

Comment: I have logged the data, and it looks correct. Also, if I swap the conditions around, the one on the right always works.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use this syntax which I think it's easier to read:

```
<div [class.Myclass]="my-condition">
```

In your case this would look like this:

```
<div class="message" [class.message-me]="item.memberId === me.memberId" [class.message-you]="item.memberId !== me.memberId">
```

So the class "message" is applied with no conditions, and the class message-me and message-you are applied conditionally

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bit of a hack, because I need to have two `ngClass`, but this works:

```
  <div [ngClass]="{'message message-me':(item.uid == me.uid)}">
    <div [ngClass]="{'message message-you':(item.uid == you.uid)}">
                <div class="message-content">{{item.message_text}}</div>
                <span class="time-tick">
                    <span class="message-timestamp">{{item.timestamp | amDateFormat: 'DD MMM YYYY  h:mm a'}}</span>
                    <div *ngIf="showTick(item) === true">
                        <span class="checkmark">
                            <div class="checkmark_stem"></div>
                            <div class="checkmark_kick"></div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```