# How to add class for multiple toggle button when it is disabled

Tags: angular, ionic3

I have multiple toggle buttons. On disable of that I want to add *class* to my parent `div` or *red color* for example as of now.

Here is demo what I have tried: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-j9amio?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts

**My html**

```
  <ion-content>
    <div *ngIf="searchResults?.details?.length > 0">
     <ion-item *ngFor="let searchResult of searchResults?.details">    
        <h2>{{searchResult?.user_id}}</h2>
        <h3>{{searchResult?.email}}</h3>
        <p>{{searchResult?.token}}</p> 
    <ion-label>on disable add red color {{searchResult?.user_id}}</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle checked="true" (ionChange)="jobIsDisabled($event,searchResult.user_id)">
    </ion-toggle>                                     
  </ion-item>             
</div>
</ion-content>
```

**My controller**

```
 searchResults = {
    "details": [{
        "user_id": "73",
        "email": "ejazanwar777@gmail.com",
        "token": "217808036f0215fee13aee8925574899"
    }, {
        "user_id": "74",
        "email": "hemanthraj2009@gmail.com",
        "token": "fe4fd5fa58075a69dd7e323cd0f1f2ad"
    }, {
        "user_id": "75",
        "email": "ggsgowtham17@gmail.com",
        "token": "9ed2839e54980a34e968e61d2bae362f"
    }, {
        "user_id": "76",
        "email": "contact@saddamhussain.com",
        "token": "e798b517a4171e1108e6809228c63c9c"
    }]
};


  jobIsDisabled(event,user_id){
     alert(user_id);
     console.log(event);
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41279830/change-classes-conditionally-ionic2

Answer (score 0):

//here is the code. it may help you

My html

```
<ion-content>
    <div *ngIf="searchResults?.details?.length > 0" >
     <ion-item *ngFor="let searchResult of searchResults?.details; let i = index;" >    
        <h2>{{searchResult?.user_id}}</h2>
        <h3>{{searchResult?.email}}</h3>
        <p>{{searchResult?.token}}</p> 
    <ion-label class="{{searchResult.class}}">on disable add red color {{searchResult?.user_id}}</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle checked="true" (ionChange)="jobIsDisabled($event,searchResult.user_id, i)">
    </ion-toggle>                                     
  </ion-item>             
</div>
</ion-content>
```

My Controller

```
jobIsDisabled(event,user_id,index){
         if(event.value == false)
           this.searchResults.details[index]['class']= 'red'; //here red is the css class
         else
           this.searchResults.details[index]['class']= '';
      }
```